# how to test my ngfor in span

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngfor

i want to test my component and i would like to test more particulary my ngFor how?

```
<a class="box-label__title-label-wrapper box-label__title-label-wrapper--margin-top"
   (click)="click()"
   [link]="link"
   [target]="target"
   [externalLink]="externalLink"
   [ngClass]="{'clickable': clickable, 'disabled': disabled}">
  <div *ngIf="headings" class="box-label__title box-label__title--label-{{display}}" maeOverflow>
    <span *ngFor="let h of headings"
          class="box-label__title-element"><span class="box-label__title-key">{{h.key}}</span>: <span class="box-label__title-value">{{h.value}}</span></span>
  </div>
  <span class="box-label__label box-label__label--{{display}}" maeOverflow>{{label || '&nbsp;'}}</span>
</a>
```

Tanks

Comment: What you want to check?Whether ngFor is working?

Comment: yes, i want to now if i have get my element of ngfor

Comment: Do you mean a unit test? Or simply to check if you can see it manually?

Comment: i mean unit test

Comment: have you done any testing yet? can you post examples of what you have tested in the component so far?

Comment: i have test lot of think but not in ngfor i don't know how